# Cannot find module '[object Object]'- Ошибка ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Это файл home.ejs:

```
<h1>Shop smart, save big!</h1>
```

Это я хочу вывести его:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});
```

Но получаю ошибку. Как можно исправить ?

```
Error: Cannot find module '[object Object]'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
        at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at new View (F:\www\e-commerce\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
```

Comment: передать в require не объект а строку

Comment: @Grundy благодарю. Так заработал: app.set('view engine', 'ejs');